# python - if statement with logical OR condition

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm a beginner in python and trying to achieve the following - need help pls...

In the below code snippet, it matches for ab but not for remaining two matches...Can anyone pls point what I'm missing.

I've a txt input which is captured in text.

```
for line in text:
  parse = re.split('\s+', line)
  print(parse)

   if ("ab" or "yx" or "12") in line:
      print("success")
      continue
     else:
      print("failure")
```

The above code matches just "ab", it doesn't work for other matches like "yx" and "12". Don't know what I'm missing.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I think you mean:

```
if "ab" in line or "yx" in line or "12" in line:
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-do-i-test-multiple-variables-against-a-value